# Twilio programmable video sdk issue

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I am using twilio programmable video sdk in my application. I've created peer to peer video chat using Twilio Programmable Video. Whenever I joined a meeting. I can see and hear opposite person but opposite person is not able to hear me or see me. And Creation of room and creation of tracks are working fine.

```
await connect(token, { 
  audio: true,
  name: this.meetingId,
  video: { width: 640 }
 }).then(room => {

  this.meetingRoom = room;
  // display the face of you
  createLocalVideoTrack().then(track => {
    const localMediaContainer = document.getElementById('local-media');
    localMediaContainer.appendChild(track.attach());
    });

  room.on('participantConnected', participant => {
    console.log(`Participant "${participant.identity}" connected`);
    participant.tracks.forEach(publication => {
      if (publication.isSubscribed) {
        const track = publication.track;
        document.getElementById('remote-media-div').appendChild(track.attach());
        localStorage.setItem('status','live');
        this.videoStyle('remote-media-div');

      }
    });
```

This is the snippet of code which I am using. It is in ionic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should listen if there any participant already added in the room for the opposite site view.

```
// Log any Participants already connected to the Room
room.participants.forEach(participant => {
                console.log(`Participant "${participant.identity}" is connected to the Room`);
                participant.tracks.forEach(publication => {
                        if (publication.isSubscribed) {
                          document.getElementById('remote-media-div').appendChild(publication.track.attach());
                        }
                      });

                     participant.on('trackSubscribed', track => {
                     document.getElementById('remote-media-div').appendChild(track.attach());
                      });
             });
```